# How to find end of line and perform addition of two integer arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, input, addition

How to find how many tokens are there in a line in the below program and then 
I need to add two integer arrays using Java, since I am more familiar with php, this is a bit challenging for me . Also I am getting the input from a text file. Hence, here is how I have my program so far.

The input file would have multiple lines like this
3736 17234 29823 84478 123745 2371 34237 823712

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Sum {

    //must use a constant for the length of the array
    static int[] total= new int[25];
    static int[] val = new int[25];
    static int line= 0;
    static int word =0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
//                  System.out.println("0");
    processFile(input);
    }

    public static void processFile(Scanner input) {
    //in this method you need to read your input file
    //. read one line at a time and call the method processLine to


    while (input.hasNextLine()) 
                {

                line++;
                String line = input.nextLine();
                Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
                                //System.out.println("1");
                processLine(input);
                //System.out.println(line);
                }


    }

    public static void processLine(Scanner data) {
    //in this method you read tokens from line that has been passed to
    // this methd as the parameter. method transfer needs to be called to
    // transfer each token into an array of length DIGITS. Note that in a
    // line you might only have one token


        while(data.hasNext())
        {

          String x = data.next();
                        //System.out.println("2");
          transfer(x,val);
        }


    }

    public static void transfer(String data, int[] digits) {
    //This method transfer the string into array of integers value.

    int len = data.length();
    int n=24;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        digits[i]=0;
                    //System.out.println("3");
        while(len>0)
        {
            //  System.out.println(data.charAt(len-1));
            char z=data.charAt(len-1);

            int d = Character.digit (z, 10); 

            digits[n]=d ;   
            len=len-1;
            n=n-1;          
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            digits[i]=0;

        for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(digits[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

            add(digits);

    }
    public static void add(int[] digits) {
            word++;
            if (word>1)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<= 4; i++)
                {
                    total= total[i]+digits[i];
                }


            }   
            if(word==0)
                total=digits;       
    }

    public static void print(int[] digits) {
    //For printing 


    }

    }
```

Comment: Your `add()` method takes only 1 argument, did you mean it to take 2 arguments (2 arrays to add)?

Comment: I am unable to make it take 2 arguments since at any time only 1 token is available. You can suggest how can it take 2 arguments. Is Storing is a good way in this case?

Comment: Please see my answer below! Why would you want to store integers as strings?

Comment: The inputs are sometimes so huge that they cannot be stored in integers.

Comment: Use long instead of int if thats the case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop to go through the 2 arrays and add each element.

Quick example code below:

```
       private int[] sumTwoArrays(int [] a, int [] b){
            if(a.length!=b.length){
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays are not of same length!");
            }
            int[] sum = new int[a.length];
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
               sum[i] = a[i]+b[i];
            }
            return sum;
       }
```

**UPDATE**: After the comments below I added another method on how to add just the elements in one array.

```
private void readFile(){
    long sum=0;
    //do your FILE I/O here
    //for each line you read into an array called input[] you call this method
    sum += sumArray(input);
    System.out.println(sum);
}

 private long sumArray(long [] a){
          long sum=0;
           for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            sum += a[i];
           }
           return sum;
  }
```

Comment: The arrays will be of max 25 length. The for loop definitely helped and works but it  updates it with the last 2 array values. I am looking for a way to know how many tokens are there in a line so that I can perform proper addition. I will also add some input data.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by last 2 update values. Do you need the total of all elements in the 2 arrays or sum of corresponding indices?

Comment: As you see the input there are multiple lines of those in a text file. I need to the sum of the values in each line. So if input has 1 2 3, Output is 1+2+3 = 6

Comment: Okay so why do you need arrays for that? Just keep a sum counter and add numbers as you read them from the file.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. That is the requirement in this case. Could not help it. :)

Comment: So the requirement is to read each line in an array and then add the values for each line?

Comment: Yes exactly and then print out each line as well

Answer (score 1):

You complicated this far more than is necesary.
To begin with, you can remove the multiple function references, the scanner class can actually parse your file into integers, and can read multiple lines - so you don't need a new scanner for each line.

I think you can simply have one Scanner per file, and then constantly use the Scanner.nextInt() function to find the next integer value in that file.

Now depending on your definition of add, there are two things you could do.

1. If you're attempting to add corresponding elements of each array, to come with with a third array where x[i] = y[i] + z[i], then you simply need a for loop with the previous statement in it. Remember of course to substitute the real names of the variables.
2. If you're attempting to add up all the integers in both the arrays to get one integer (or long), you could use two for loops, one after another and constantly add the current element of the current array to a variable.